# How to send a Word document as body of an email with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, outlook

I've created a macro that works with outlook and excel that will use a list of email addresses (in excel) and send all those addresses an email (in outlook). I want to take a word document (from microsoft word) and use it as the body of the email. The problem is, I will have images in the word document and I need the word document to keep it's formatting. Right now, my VBA takes the content of my word document but the formatting is gone and images aren't included. This is my code:

```
Sub spamEmail()
   'Setting up the Excel variables.
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim iCounter As Integer
   Dim Dest As Variant
   Dim SDest As String
   Dim Excel As Object
   Dim Name As String
   Dim Word As Object
   Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
   Dim doc As Word.Document
   Dim itm As Object
   Dim MsgTxt As String

   'Set the outlook account to send.
   Set oAccount = Application.Session.Accounts.Item(2)

   'Create excel object.
   Set Excel = CreateObject("excel.application")
   Excel.Visible = True
   Excel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Deryl Lam\Documents\Book1.xlsx")
   Excel.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Activate

   'Create a word object.
   Set Word = CreateObject("word.application")
   Set doc = Word.Documents.Open _
   (FileName:="C:\Users\Deryl Lam\Documents\emailBody.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
   'Pulls text from file for message body
    MsgTxt = doc.Range(Start:=doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, _
    End:=doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.End)

   'Loop through the excel worksheet.
       For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1).Columns(1))

           'Create an email for each entry in the worksheet.
           Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
           With oMail
            SDest = Cells(iCounter, 1).Value
            If SDest = "" Then
             'Dont do anything if the entry is blank.
            Else
             'Do additional formatting on the BCC and Subject lines, add the body text from the spreadsheet, and send.
             Name = Cells(iCounter, 2).Value
             .BCC = SDest
             .Subject = "FYI"
             .Body = "Dear " & Name & "," & vbCrLf & MsgTxt

             'SendUsingAccount is new in Office 2007
             'Change Item(1)to the account number that you want to use
             .SendUsingAccount = oAccount

             .Send
            End If
           End With
       Next iCounter


   'Clean up the Outlook application.
   Set olMailItm = Nothing
   Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've searched all over google for a solution but I haven't found one. How can I send a word document as the body of the email with it's formatting in tact and the images included?

Comment: For one thing, you're getting the contents of your Word doc as a string (in the variable MsgTxt) but that by definition won't include any images.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting the contents of your template document as a string, which by definition will not contain any formatting or images. You should instead copy the contents to the clipboard and then paste them into the new email.

Something like this:

```
Sub emailFromDoc()
    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim oMail As MailItem

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open(...path to your doc...)
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    set wd = Nothing

    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With oMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're the man. I wonder why you need .Display to actually behave correctly. Without .Display, it will send the email but without the body. Thanks Patrick

Comment: very strange - this solution does **not** work with `.Send` so not viable solution for automated emailing

Comment: @urdearboy true, I just came to this and probably the only quick solution for now is to have `.Display` and `.Send` together to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If not for the images, you could save the document as an HTML file, read its contents, then set the MailItem.HTMLBody property.

Images are more involved. I don't see a straightforward way to bring them into a message body.

Comment: I've found this that's a little helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_CreatingAFormattedMessage. Using Inspector.WordEditor you can "Create a formatted email message with embedded images." But it doesn't show you how and I've tried looking for WordEditor functions on google but I can't find it

Comment: Inspector.WordEditor property returns Word.Document object - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211897(v=office.12).aspx - but I don't think it will let you import a new DOC file in place of an existing document.

Comment: I am not importing new DOC files. I am opening up an existing file

Comment: If you have a Word.Document object corresponding to the message body of a particular Outlook message, your DOC file would need to be imported into that document.