# Embedding an HTML file with images in an Outlook email generated by Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, image, outlook

I want to send a personalized email generated by Excel VBA.

The email contains personalized text followed by a html file that contains images.

I tried the following code but the images are not displayed.

```
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Html_Doc()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim sText As String            

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\....\invite.htm")

    Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
        sText = oFS.ReadAll()
    Loop

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'strbody = personalized email body generated here

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .display
        .To = ToAdd
        .CC = 
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test Email"
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True

        ' the html file is appended here to the personalized email body generated
        .HTMLBody = strbody & sText
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The invite.htm referred above contains images which are not visible when the email is sent. Neither in the email messages sent nor in the email messages received.

Comment: I believe there may be some issue with your .htm file.  Are the images local references?  I took your code verbatim and  set .HTMLBody = "<img src =(put image url here)>" and i had no issues loading an image. It also worked with generic strings in place of strBody and the HTML snippet in place of the sText.

Comment: There are multiple images in the .html file. There is also text which is formatted into table with two columns. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here ia an example that works for me you need to adapt it according to your needs.
This will embed the image in the body of the email and will attach it from what I remember. Please note you need to display the email first and then send it that is the only way to show on different device, i learn that the hard way. It can be done via code as the below example if you want to display and review the email just comment out the `.Send` after you are happy you can press manually `send`.

```
Option Explicit
Dim titleName As String
Dim firstName As String
Dim lastName As String
Dim fullName As String
Dim clientEmail As String
Dim ccEmail As String
Dim bccEmail As String
Dim emailMessage As String

Sub GenerateInfo()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim cRow As Long

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With WS
        lrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For cRow = 2 To lrow
            If Not .Range("L" & cRow).value = "" Then
                titleName = .Range("D" & cRow).value
                firstName = .Range("E" & cRow).value
                lastName = .Range("F" & cRow).value
                fullName = firstName & " " & lastName
                clientEmail = .Range("L" & cRow).value

                Call SendEmail

                .Range("Y" & cRow).value = "Yes"
                .Range("Y" & cRow).Font.Color = vbGreen

            Else
                .Range("Y" & cRow).value = "No"
                .Range("Y" & cRow).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next cRow
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Process completed!", vbInformation

End Sub
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim insertPhoto As String
    Dim photoSize As String

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Marius.htm"

    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    insertPhoto = "C:\Users\marius\Desktop\Presale.jpg" 'Picture path
    photoSize = "<img src=""cid:Presale.jpg""height=400 width=400>" 'Change image name here

    emailMessage = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear " & titleName & " " & fullName & "," & _
                    "<p>I hope my email will find you very well." & _
                    "<p>Our <strong>sales preview</strong> starts on Thursday the 22nd until Sunday the 25th of November." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to welcoming you into the store to shop on preview.<p>" & _
                    "<p> It really is the perfect opportunity to get some fabulous pieces for the fast approaching festive season." & _
                    "<p>Please feel free to contact me and book an appointment." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to seeing you then." & _
                    "<p>" & photoSize & _
                    "<p>Kind Regards," & _
                    "<br>" & _
                    "<br><strong>Marius</strong>" & _
                    "<br>Assistant Store Manager" & _
                    "<p>"


    With outlookMail
        .To = clientEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRIVATE SALE"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Attachments.Add insertPhoto, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Including photo insert and signature
        '.HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Only signature
        .Importance = 2
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Display
        .Send

    End With

    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: There are multiple images in the .html file. There is also text which is formatted into table with two columns. Does this change anything?

Comment: Yes you need to adapt it to your specific needs. Declare another global variable to copy the table into in the loop just before the ‘call SendEmail’. Depends how exactly your excel file is you need to tweak the login ex maybe the table is in a different worksheet than putting it in the for loop will make no sense and you need another way to do it maybe another loop that goes through the second sheet or if you only have one table that you need to send to all you don’t need to put it in a loop just set the range on that table and you can call the variable in the sendEmail.

Comment: Regarding your .html file with multiple images I’m not sure what you mean exactly. If .html is like a container for multiple images and you want to display them in the body of the email that will not work. You need to have individual images in a folder and have a good name convention ex Img1 and do a for loop and increment I every time depending on how many img you want to add or the easy way if you have 10 img declare 10 variable for each img and were you see in my code photoSize replace it with yours in by one and you need to use ‘&’ in between and good to go.

Comment: If .html is like a container for multiple images and you want to display them in the "body of the email" - Yes. This is the issue. Then there are hyperlinks attached to the images. Looping is complex. I am contemplating making it .mht file. But not sure the code will work. We need a binary mode reader in GetFile. It cannot be opened as a text stream I guess. –

Comment: may be the solution in this question will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609112/how-to-send-a-word-document-as-body-of-an-email-with-vba But how to put the copied content from word document below a customized email content that is generated using some variables in the excel fields.

Comment: It might be easier if you just have just the images and assign to variable then you can easily insert it in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Remember:
on the .attachments.add you need the full path and name
If you want to see the pictures in the email body then no path in "<img" definitions but must have the same file name.
It took me a while to work this out.

:)