# How to add additional text/images to the body of a VBA generated email?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently the vba code creates an outlook email item that takes the contents of a word document as its email body. How do I add additional text/images to the body?

The answer to this SO question is how I am creating the outlook item:
[How to send a Word document as body of an email with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609112/how-to-send-a-word-document-as-body-of-an-email-with-vba)

Here is the actual code I am using:

```
Sub email()
Mail_Object, o As Variant

    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open("(word address)")
    doc.Content.Copy
    Set wd = Nothing

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
            .Subject = "subject"
            .To = "to"
            Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
            editor.Content.Paste

            'here something like: body = body & "additional text"
            .Display
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set Mail_Object = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML tags if you define your object as .HTMLBody. You can try to do it as following:

```
MailItem.HTMLBody = Content & "<br>" & "<br>"
MailItem.HTMLBody = Content &  "<B>" & "<h3>" & "DRAFT: Your Additional Content Here" & "</h3>" & "</B>" & "<br>" & _
"Your Additional Image Here: " & "<br>"&  "<img src="image/url">
```

Answer (score 0):

As you named the excel tag, here are some examples to add a shape or Excel cells as picture into your email's body (without html knowledge):

```
With Editor.Range

    .Collapse wdCollapseStart
    .InsertBefore "Hi there," & vbCrLf & "here's my picture:" & vbCrLf

    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter vbCrLf & "Best wishes," & vbCrLf

    .Collapse wdCollapseStart
    .PasteSpecial link:=False, _
        DataType:=wdPasteShape, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
    '.Paste
    '.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
    '.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
End With
```