# Copy word doc body to outlook email: RTE 5

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to copy all of content of a word doc into a Outlook email body while keeping the format and was looking to follow the solution found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609112/how-to-send-a-word-document-as-body-of-an-email-with-vba) post but am getting an error on the following line:                `.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText`. When the error handler is removed, I get `RTE5: Invalid procedure call or argument`

---

Any idea why this line is throwing an error or how to correct?

---

```
Sub Sender(Target As Range)


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim wd As Object
Dim editor As Object
Dim doc As Object

Dim fp As String
fp = "C:\Users\urdearboy\"

Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = wd.documents.Open(fp & "mydearfile.docx")
doc.Content.Copy
doc.Close
Set wd = Nothing

On Error GoTo BNP:

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@so.com"
            .to = Target.Offset(, 2)
            .Subject = "Hi Mom"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText                 '<----- ERROR LINE
            Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
            editor.Content.Paste
            
            .Display
            '.Send
            
            Target.Offset(, -1) = "Sent"
        End With
        
BNP:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

Context: I decided to go with the Word to Outlook copy because the file has a lot of formatting and photos and getting the right format strictly in Outlook HTML sounds like a nightmare. If done manually, this would essentially be a complete `CTRL + A + Copy` from word and `CTRL + V` in Outlook which keeps all formatting, photos, and gifs with correct format. The goal here is to mimic that process in VBA. If there is a better solution, open to thoughts there as well

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Outlook Library set?

Comment: If not, `Const olFormatRichText as Long = 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're late-binding, then add:

```vb
Const olFormatRichText As Long = 3
```

(seems like you didn't have `Option Explicit` on too...)

You can find the appropriate value of `olFormatRichText` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat).

Comment: I thought olFormatRichText was synonymous with 3. Agh yes, `Option Explicit`... new work machine and have not turned that setting back on yet. That would have caught this error though?

Comment: Yes it would have flagged it as undeclared.

Comment: very displeased to find out the GIF doesn't seem to work. It works when in `Display` but after sending it's a still image. Not relevant to this question - not sure if it's worth the work to get that to work when I can attach it fairly quickly.

Comment: I missed the point about the GIF. Yeah I feel the answer is probably somewhere on SO or elsewhere online.