# Embed .docx\xlsx in Outlook via Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, ms-word, office-automation

could you please tell me how to do this?

I tried a bunch of different options, but all I could get was System.__ComObject and the xml in it

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "e@mail.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject"

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\1.docx")

$Mail.HTMLBody = 

$Doc.Close($true)
$Word.Quit($true)

$inspector = $Mail.Getinspector
$inspector.Display()
```

---

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\1.docx")
$Doc.Content.Copy()

$Doc.Close($true)
$Word.Quit($true)

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "random@email.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject"

$Mail.HTMLBody = $Mail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Content.Paste()

$Mail.GetInspector().Display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\1.docx")
$Doc.Content.Copy()

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "random@email.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject"

echo $Mail.HTMLBody = $Mail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Content.Paste()

$Mail.GetInspector().Display()

$Doc.Close($true)
$Word.Quit($true)
```

it worked, but I don't understand why it doesn't work without echo

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\1.docx")
$Doc.Content.Copy()

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "random@email.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject"

$Mail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Content.Paste()

$Mail.GetInspector().Display()

$Doc.Close($true)
$Word.Quit($true)
```

Comment: There is no need to set the HTMLBody property if you use the `WordEditor` one.

Comment: As implied by @EugeneAstafiev's comment, all you need to do is call `$Mail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Content.Paste()`, which will automatically reflect the content in `.HTMLBody`, I presume. The `echo` command _bypassed_ your mistaken attempt to assign the method call to `$Mail.HTMLBody` (`$Mail.HTMLBody` and `=` simply became _arguments_ whose value to _display_), while still performing the method call itself. In other words: replace the entire `echo ...` line with just `$Mail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Content.Paste()`

Answer (score 2):

To copy the document content from a Word file you need to use the `Copy()` method available in the Word object model. Then you can paste the content right into the message body of the email created in Outlook. For that you need to get an instance of the `Inspector` class and call the `WordEditor` property, for example:

```
$objWordEditor = $Mail.GetInspector().WordEditor
```

After that you can call the Paste method to insert the copied content:

```
$objWordEditor.Content.Paste()
```

See [How to send a Word document as body of an email with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609112/how-to-send-a-word-document-as-body-of-an-email-with-vba) for more information.

Comment: What value does the `Body` or `HTMLBody` return after?

Comment: Body - Blank, HTMLBody - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 16.0.16501.20190">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->

</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: I edited the code above, tags and styles appeared in HTMLBody, but in the Outlook window is empty, as well as in the clipboard is also copied and I can paste manually from the buffer